# Frontend, Front-end or Front End Developer?

Tags: frontend

I've seen it written a number of ways. The same is true of backend, back-end and back end. How should I write it on my CV?

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=backend&oq=backend&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.963j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=backend&oq=backend&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.963j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=frontend

Comment: This should probably be on Programmers.SE

Comment: Or even [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com/) as it's more a language thing I think.

Comment: Nevertheless +1 because you actually care about the correctness of the language used on your CV

Comment: @poorsod: Absolutely not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GoogleFight](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=frontend&word2=front%20end)

Shows that "front end" is used more often.

EDIT:

But for a serious answer, this has been asked on english.stackexchange.com

Here is the link:

[Is it “front-end”, “frontend”, or “front end”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/is-it-front-end-frontend-or-front-end)

Comment: Nice one, but although many politicians seem to think otherwise, repeating a lie often enough doesn't make it a truth :)  I think the real question here is how these words should be [compounded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound) and there's a pretty good chance that the "correct" answer depends on what side of the Atlantic you are...

Comment: Here is a more serious answer :P